# Sharing a Win7 Mappable Network Drive in Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a ghetto windows server 2008 r2 server that I basically run as a file server. I would like to create a share that can be mapped as a network drive by a Windows 7 Pro PC.  How can I do this?

I've gathered that I probably need to setup a VPN network on my Server 2008 R2 box and then grant my Win7 PC access.

Is there anything else I am overlooking or is there a better way to do this?  I basically just want to be able to edit xml files on my Win7 PC without having to ftp them back and forth.

Answer (score 3):

...right click the folder with files you want to share and select sharing?

Comment: The computers aren't on the same network...

Comment: Not sure this was spelled out in the question...but in that case, you'd probably use site-to-site VPN connection to connect the two networks.

Comment: I wasn't clear in the question.  Thanks for the answer; just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking something.